# Playing local mp3 files via JS in Lollipop chrome

Tags: javascript, audio

I try to play local mp3 files via JS , this works in desktop chrome by not in android chrome (the file in the example of course is not local)

```
play("https://www.soundjay.com/misc/bell-ringing-01.mp3");
 function play(h)
{
 a = new Audio(h);
 a.play(h);
}
```

Update: it works with a button call but not for future setTimeout play calls

```
function start()
{
play("mp3/bell.mp3");
setTimeout("start();",3000);
}

<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```

Comment: what is the chrome version .check if there any errors? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: seems up to date - 61.0.31...

Comment: you have to touch an audio tag on mobile to get it to play. your is invisible and thus cannot be touched and played. call play() from an onclick() event.

Comment: Thanks ,it works.....but not for a future setTimeout play. Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added

```
  <audio id="sound" ></audio>
  <button onclick="start()" style="font-size:300%;">Start</button>


 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 audio = document.getElementById('sound');
 });
```

and in the function

```
audio.src = n;
audio.play();
```